# Why does gradient check in batch normalization is not working?

Tags: python, neural-network, gradient-descent, batch-normalization

I have a self-implementation of a neural network with learning rate, momentum, L1/L2 regularization and batch normalization. When I perform gradient checking, all the gradients are correct, except when I use batch normalization

I wrote a python code to test gradient checking on batch normalization only:
https://gist.github.com/arnaldog12/9ba321cfdb18b6955a83403df1a7f514

For the code above, I tried to remove all the unnecessary code as momentum, dropout, and L1/L2 regularization. If you just copy and paste the code above in some python environment with numpy, it will work.

I believe the error is in the gradient I pass to **batchnorm_backward** function and the gradients I compute later. Currently, I have been debugging the code, but I have not been able to find what's wrong.

Have someone already performed gradient checking on batch normalization?
If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After some time, I realized that, in order to check the gradients of batch norm, you must compute the cost as if the model were in training mode. If you check the gradients as if the model were in test mode, the batch norm will use the running mean and variance instead of batch mean and batch variance, and the gradient checking will fail.